# angular animation fade in

Tags: angular, animation, angular5, css-animations

The guys have a question, there are 4 buttons, and on the main page there are 4 blocks, with each click I need to fadeIn the first block appeared and the rest were hiding, then the second and so on.

The problem is that when you press the first button, the first block hides in its place and the second block jumps to the first place, here's the code:

```
 animations: [
    trigger('anyState', [
      state('inactive', style({
        opacity: '0.0',
        transform: 'scale(0.0)',
        display: 'none'
      })),
      state('active',   style({
        opacity: '1.0',
        transform: 'scale(1.0)',
        display: 'block'
      })),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('1000ms ease-in')),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('1000ms ease-out'))
    ]),
```

I want to get the result so that when the second button is clicked, the second block appears on the same place as the first block, and I get that when clicking on the second button the first block gently hides and then the second one jumps to the first place.

Help solve this problem, please!

Answer (score 0):

There's an Angular module I've put together providing that functionality, although it slides the elements instead of fading them.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-slide-down